# Strptime not able to convert date and time

Tags: r

My attempt to format date like this results in NA NA. Neither the date nor the time is getting converted. What am I doing wrong?

```
    x <- strptime(c("2013-12-12", "08:43:24.967"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the format string that you have supplied, `strptime` expects a vector of date-time strings.  You have a vector containing date and time as separate vector elements.  This is incorrect.

Instead of passing `c("2013-12-12", "08:43:24.967")` (two elements, date then time), you need to pass `"2013-12-12 08:43:24.967"` (one element, date-time).

The data you have can be put in the proper format with `paste`:

```
strptime(paste("2013-12-12", "08:43:24.967"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2013-12-12 08:43:24"
```

The fractional seconds aren't printed above, because the default is to not print them.  But the expression does capture them (with the default `options(digits.secs=NULL)`).  They would be printed with the proper format string for output, or a specification of the number of digits to print (e.g. `options(digits.secs=3)`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a date string as first argument to strptime function follwed by the date format. It seems like you entered 0 in the date format string and please remove that milliseconds part in the date string.

You can use statement like this:

strptime("2013-12-12 08:43:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: That's not a `0` in the format string, it's an `O` and it has an effect.  It is neither necessary to remove the `O` nor necessary to remove the factional seconds.